# Show dhcp ip addresses are running out?

Tags: networking, router, cisco, cisco-ios

In Cisco, which show command can be used to determine if DHCP IP addresses are running out within the network ?

Comment: This question is not about programming, so it is off-topic here, on the programmers site. You should try to ask this question on [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is the programmers' site to ask questions and get answers about programming. SE has sites for a variety of subjects. You should ask your questions on the correct site. The Network Engineering site is for networking questions in a business network. [SF] is for servers in a business environment. [su] is for general computing questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
show ip dhcp binding
```

Display list of dhcp bindings

```
show ip dhcp server statistics
```

Display dhcp server statistics

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ipaddr/command/reference/fipras_r/1rfdhcp.pdf

Comment: Don't answer off topic questions.